# vanilla C fopen path to adjacent folder

Tags: c, path, fopen

I'm writing vanilla C code on a Mac OS10.4.  I simply want to fopen() a file for write IN A FOLDER adjacent to the executable.

I can't for the life of me figure out the correct syntax for the
path name.

```
FILE  *fout;

fopen( fout, "foldername/filename", "w" )
```

sure doesn't work.

I'm willing to reach back to the root if necessary, but can't
figure that one out, either.

Can someone help with this "simple" question?

Comment: What error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `fout = fopen("foldername/filename", "w" );`?

Comment: @MByD: you are absolutely right: `FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);`

Comment: What do you mean by "adjacent"?

Comment: I apologize for neglecting to mention that the folder already exists in the same location as the executable.  "foldername/filename" creates a file in the executable location with the name foldername/filename.

Answer (score 3):

If the current working directory of the process is `/Users/you/your_program` and you want the file in `/Users/you/foldername/filename`, then you need to specify:

```
fp = fopen("../foldername/filename", "w");
```

The `..` moves up one level.  This is the pattern on Unix and Windows.  This is a reasonable interpretation of 'adjacent to' - it creates the file in a folder at the same level in the hierarchy as the current one.

Comment: While of course the call to fopen is already plain wrong in the question. So what else is/was missing? Still +1.

Comment: @STATUS: I didn't even notice that the function call was being abused so badly.

Comment: As I replied to your e-mail, Jonathan, that "path" creates a file at the executable location named ../foldername/filename